# Generate random string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I would like to convert this Python code into JavaScript using Node.JS so I can use it in my application. How may I do this in Node.JS JavaScript.

**Current Python code:**

```
import random
import string

chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
ERC = []
for i in list(range(15)):
    ERC[i] = '-'.join(''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(5)) for i in range(4))
```

The above code gets random characters from the variable which acts as a whitelist of alphanumeric characters I want to use, the format is 4 segments of 5 random characters separated by a dash. I have looked and found [random-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/random-js) but I haven't found it very concluding for my needs. I need something like [node-randomstring](https://github.com/klughammer/node-randomstring), but that the alphabetical characters are in upper case.
Math.random() doesn't work for me because it returns numbers between 0 and 1.

An example of the final output (from my code) looks like `SY51R-APE9S-WM8ZC-L3ZP2`

Comment: I assume you mean just Javascript in which case yes.

Comment: Yes, I did. I know how to do everything except for the random choice of characters, I'm trying to figure out how to do it in NodeJS

Comment: I'm not too familiar with JS stuff, but I was under the impression anything in JS works in NodeJS, which is just a framework. A quick google search reveals the Math.random() function in JS, which can do what  you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, anything JavaScript can work with NodeJS. Math.random() only returns numbers between 0 and 1, which isn't what I want

Comment: Yes, but the idea is that you can be a bit creative and figure out how to use a random function to get what you need, or post and hope someone will come to the rescue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my complete answer here: [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

While the answer provided by @tané-tachyon was good, it wasn't as random as the answer provided on the linked question.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For choosing your random characters just do

```
chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)]
```